# Unity GUI TextField in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

so I'm making a sign up scene in Unity, and when I used this script to put textfields and a button, but when I play I can't type in the textfield. What is wrong with my code?

```
void OnGUI () {

    string email = "";
    string username = "";
    string password = "";
    string confirm = "";

    email = GUI.TextField (new Rect (250, 93, 250, 25), email, 40);
    username = GUI.TextField ( new Rect (250, 125, 250, 25), username, 40);
    password = GUI.PasswordField (new Rect (250, 157, 250, 25), password, "*"[0], 40);
    confirm = GUI.PasswordField (new Rect (300, 189, 200, 25), confirm, "*"[0], 40);

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (300, 250, 100, 30), "Sign-up")) {
        Debug.Log(email + " " + username + " " + password + " " + confirm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Store the input variables as a member of your *class/script*, not the method. Each frame you reset it back to an empty string wiping out what the user was trying to input.

Note from the [Unity3D documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.TextField.html) regarding the `text` parameter:

> Text to edit. The return value of this function should be assigned
>   back to the string as shown in the example.

Try changing your code to:

```
//notice these are pulled out from the method and now attached to the script
string email = ""; 
string username = "";
string password = "";
string confirm = "";

void OnGUI () {

    email = GUI.TextField (new Rect (250, 93, 250, 25), email, 40);
    username = GUI.TextField ( new Rect (250, 125, 250, 25), username, 40);
    password = GUI.PasswordField (new Rect (250, 157, 250, 25), password, "*"[0], 40);
    confirm = GUI.PasswordField (new Rect (300, 189, 200, 25), confirm, "*"[0], 40);

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (300, 250, 100, 30), "Sign-up")) {
        Debug.Log(email + " " + username + " " + password + " " + confirm);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DannikaRodriguez if it wored you should select the *Tick* next to this answer to indicate it is the correct answer for your question.